# Running Matlab via PBS fails

Tags: matlab, pbs

I am trying to run Matlab 2013 via PBS and I get the following error:

```
libXv.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can run my code in Matlab's GUI mode though. I tried using LD_PRELOAD to point to the library as under, but that did not help either.

```
setenv LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1
```

Any suggestions on how to go about resolving this error?

Answer (score 1):

When running Matlab via PBS you run actual Matlab scripts on the nodes of the cluster that probably do not have any GUI components installed including the X client libraries such as `libXv.so.1`.

You probably do not want to run Matlab in a GUI mode via a  batch system unless it is an interactive job. In case you just want to run a script, try specifying matlab command line in your PBS script as follows:

```
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "myfunc"
```

Where `myfunc` is the Matlab command that you want to run on the cluster.